# making make without using make

Tags: linux, makefile, rpm, yum

I'm using CentOS but because of a mistake, many packages were removed. so I don't have yum and rpm. so I want to make yum manually from source code, but i don't have make either. I know everything will be made with "make package". but what about make itself??
Is there a way to install the "make package"?

Comment: If your goal is really just to restore your system, reinstalling on a new disk and copying stuff over is going to be much, much easier and faster. Then google "backups".

Answer (score 1):

Make can be bootstrapped, i. e., like an operating system, a compiler, etc. a version can be made of it which can then host itself. But, don't forget: the very first version of make has to be compiled manually. Grab the source code, perform `gcc -c` or the like on it, then link all the object files together.

Comment: I don't have gcc. How to install it.

Comment: Well, then you're basically screwed.

Comment: @babak6 On OS X, you can grab a gcc binary by installing XCode. Is there something similar on the Linux side? If you have internet access, you could probably get a working version. But unless you have the time to try and re-bootstrap the system, a fresh install might be the best option. It wouldn't be wasted time IMO if you do try to re-configure the system. You'll probably learn a whole lot about how *nix systems work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get rpm and yum reinstalled, you should be able to reboot the system to a CentOS rescue CD. This should have rpm and scp available.

See http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-boot.html
and http://ekuric.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/how-to-install-rpm-package-in-rescue-mode/

You may also find more help (and sympathy) at http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

for bootstrapping you can compile make and gcc (with dependencies that are missing on target) on other machine and install it in directory (configure --prefix=..). then copy it directory on your centos. if arch is different use cross-compiling

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would probably be a Live system.

If that won't work, I would use a different approach:

1. Manually install the very basic RPMs which are needed. This is, well, `rpm`. To install that without having it, you could use (on a different, working system) call `rpm2cpio` and transfer the resulting cpio archive to the system to be rescued. There it can be extracted with `cpio -id`.
2. Now you should have a working RPM. (If not, repeat step 1 with all packages which are probably needed.) So you can install every `.rpm` which is needed for a working `yum`. Do the same with the manually installed stuff so that it is properly recorded in the RPM database.
3. If you have a working `yum` now, you can go on and automatically install everything else needed.